# How to edit a mailing list using gmail API?

Tags: gmail-api

I have a requirement where I want to edit a mailing list - add and remove members - quite frequently (weekly, and sporadically, daily).
Going through gmail API documentation, I didn't find anything that could point me to a solution for the same.
Is this feature supported? If yes, can you point me to a doc page?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_groups)
.

> **Contact Group Entry**
>
> Contacts can be placed into user-defined groups. You can create, retrieve, update, and delete these groups using the Contacts Data API, and you can add contacts to a group or remove contacts from a group. For details, see the following sections.

To [create a new contact group](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contact_groups), send an authorized POST request to the contact groups feed URL with the contact group entry data in the body:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/{userEmail}/full
```

With the appropriate value in place of `userEmail`. Be noted that the special `userEmail` value `default` can be used to refer to the authenticated user.